# Проблема множества одинаковых id на странице

Tags: html, jquery

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблица.

```
<tr>
<td><div class="cart-image">
<img src="/img.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="name">Элемент1<span class="color">Цвет</span>
<span class="name-articul">Арт. PM</span>
</div>
</td>
<td class="price">130 руб.</td>
<td id="cart-number-617" class="cart-number" rel="6"><div>
<span class="minus"></span>
<span class="cart-item">1</span>
<span class="plus"></span>
</div>
</td>
<td id="cart-summ-617" class="cart-summ" rel="6"><span>130</span> руб.</td>
<td id="cart-refuse-617" class="cart-refuse" rel="6"><span>удалить</span>   </td>
</tr>
```

Нажатие на `<td id="cart-refuse-617" class="cart-refuse" rel="6"><span>удалить</span>`
Запускает скрипт

```
$("#cart-refuse-" + id + "[rel=" + color + "]").css({"display":"none"});
```

Но возникла проблема таких строк в таблице мб много, и `<td id="cart-refuse-617" class="cart-refuse" rel="6"><span>удалить</span>`  ид у данного поля повторяется - их много на стр, вследствие чего скрипт выполняется только у самого верхнего элемента.
Структуру таблицы изменить невозможно.

Comment: id - это уникальный идентификатор элемента и таковым должен быть.
на странице не должно быть несколько элементов с одинаковым id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте html5 аттрибуты data-*

```
<td data-id="cart-summ-617" class="cart-summ" rel="6"><span>130</span> руб.</td>
```